# Request for member ______ which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

Good Day wonderful computer people of the planet Earth!

Here is the struct in a file called AudioQueue.h:

```
typedef struct AudioQueueBuffer {
const UInt32                    mAudioDataBytesCapacity;
void * const                    mAudioData;
UInt32                          mAudioDataByteSize;
void *                          mUserData;

const UInt32                    mPacketDescriptionCapacity;
AudioStreamPacketDescription *  const mPacketDescriptions;
UInt32                          mPacketDescriptionCount;
#ifdef __cplusplus
AudioQueueBuffer() : mAudioDataBytesCapacity(0), mAudioData(0), mPacketDescriptionCapacity(0), mPacketDescriptions(0) { }
#endif
} AudioQueueBuffer;

/*!
@typedef    AudioQueueBufferRef
@abstract   An pointer to an AudioQueueBuffer.
*/
typedef AudioQueueBuffer *AudioQueueBufferRef;
```

And then later on there is this in the header of AudioPlayer.h:

```
    AudioQueueBufferRef             mBuffers[kNumberBuffers];
```

And then what I'm trying to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {

    printf("%i\n", &mBuffers[i].mAudioData );

    XThrowIfError(AudioQueueAllocateBufferWithPacketDescriptions(mQueue, bufferByteSize, (isFormatVBR ? mNumPacketsToRead : 0), &mBuffers[i]), "AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed");
```

Basically I'm trying to access the information in mAudioData, but get the error:

```
request for member 'mAudioData' in '((AQPlayer*)this)->AQPlayer::mBuffers[i]', which is of non-class type 'AudioQueueBuffer*'
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it's an operator precedence error? Try -> instead of . to access mAudioData.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AudioQueueBufferRef` is an `AudioQueueBuffer` pointer. `mBuffers` is an array of these. So when referring to members of elements of `mBuffers`, you should be using `->` not `.`:

```
printf("%i\n", &mBuffers[i]->mAudioData );
```

(I'm guessing you probably don't want the `&` either - the address held by mAudioData seems a more useful thing to be printing than the position of that member within its AudioQueueBuffer structure)

Answer (score 1):

you're dealing with an array of pointers to AudioQueueBuffer.

try accessing fields using `->` instead of `.`:

```
assert(mBuffers[i]);
std::cout << &mBuffers[i]->mAudioData << "\n";
```

EDIT: moonshadow beat me to it